# Emacs shell doesn't recognize python command

Tags: python, shell, emacs, compilation, command

I have been trying to do some python coding in emacs but the shell of emacs does not compile my code. It keeps showing this error 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' I have already added my Python path to system variables so it runs python in command prompt properly but not in emacs shell
this is my init.dl file

```
(require 'package)

;; Adds the Melpa archive to the list of available repositories
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

;; Initializes the package infrastructure
(package-initialize)

;; If there are no archived package contents, refresh them
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; Installs packages
;;
;; myPackages contains a list of package names
(defvar myPackages
  '(better-defaults    ;; Set up some better Emacs defaults
    elpy               ;;Emacs lisp python environment
    material-theme                  ;; Theme
    )
  )

;; Scans the list in myPackages
;; If the package listed is not already installed, install it
(mapc #'(lambda (package)
          (unless (package-installed-p package)
            (package-install package)))
      myPackages)

;; ===================================
;; Basic Customization
;; ===================================

;;(setq inhibit-startup-message t)    ;; Hide the startup message
;;(load-theme 'material t)            ;; Load material theme
(global-linum-mode t)               ;; Enable line numbers globally

;; ====================================
;; Development Setup
;; ====================================
;; Enable elpy
(elpy-enable)
```

Comment: There are different ways to invoke a shell in emacs. Which one do you use?

Comment: I type M-x shell

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 7(32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

This package will help you: [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

You can install it via Emacs' built-in package manager Melpa by running

```
M-x package-install RET exec-path-from-shell RET
```

Then, put the following line in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and restart Emacs:

```lisp
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```